# Tableview crash in height for row At indexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, heightforrowatindexpath

[image]I am implementing a tableview with 2 xib files.
But in some devices, it's crashing in height for rowAt: function (as per crash logs)
Below is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 340.0
        } else {
            return (contentHeights[indexPath.row] + 70)
        }
    }




  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “customId1”, for: indexPath) as? customCell1
        if let details = Details{
            print(detail)
        }            
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        if cell == nil {
    print(“nil cell”)                
        }
        return cell!
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:customId2, for: indexPath)  as? customCell2
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none

        if cell == nil {
            print(“nil cell”)
        }
        return cell!
    }
}
```

I am populating wkweview content in this cellforRow and then reloading the specific row on setting the tableview content.

Although it's working fine on all the devices but crashing on 2 devices out of 350 devices.

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: By doing this you can skip error but check why cell is coming to null. And also check in heightforRowAt contentHeights having that index or not

       if cell == nil {
            print(“nil cell”)
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        return cell!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the state (the `dataSource`) of your table view is synchronized with your actual data (not the `dataSource`)?

What I'm seeing from your code is that the computation for the row's height involves an array item access. Be sure that the table view's data is fully synchronized by calling the necessary methods to reload the table view state (such as `beginUpdates`-`endUpdates` and `reloadData` methods).

Also, do use `assert`ion in your `cellForRowAt` method. It's useful for development purposes and avoids using `print` statements that continues execution of your code and can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I'll be using assert from now on. Coming to arrayItem,i am implementing webviews in 2 xib, where data will get populated in the webview, based on content,I'll calculate the height and replace the value in array. I have check array in rowForHeight is not throwing nul pointer exception

Answer (score -1):

By doing this you can skip error but check why cell is coming to null. And also check in heightforRowAt contentHeights having that index or not

```
   if cell == nil {
        print(“nil cell”)
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    return cell!
```